# Is there a variant of 溏 without the 口 component that's used in Taiwan?

Tags: taiwan, character-variant

On a sign outside a breakfast eatery in Taoyuan, Taiwan I saw a character I didn't know, that Google Translate with the phone camera didn't translate, and that I couldn't find in Pleco.

[image: mystery character]

It looks like 溏 but without the "mouth" component in the lower right. It looks like it has a "person" component there instead, but maybe that is part of the strokes above it, I'm pretty rusty.

Is this a common variant of 溏? Semantically I thought it more likely to be a variant of "sugar" 糖, but that has more differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

焿 is a character on its own.

ZDic：http://www.zdic.net/z/1d/js/713F.htm

> gēng
>   〔～子寮湾〕地名。在中国台湾省东北海岸。

Wiktionary: https://zh.wiktionary.org/zh-hans/%E7%84%BF

> “焿”是“羹”的异体字，为台湾本地自创的形声俗字。

羹 means '(thick) soup, broth'.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

- The left hand side of that character is「火」, not「氵」(unlike in「溏」)
- 「庚」is not a variant component of「唐」.「唐」(*boastful, exaggerative*; [Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)) [OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese): **/*[N-]rˁaŋ/**) is constructed from semantic「口」(*mouth*) and phonetic「庚」(**/*kˤraŋ/**).

---

「焿」(*thick broth, soup*; Pinyin: **gēng**) is constructed from semantic「火」(*fire*) and phonetic「庚」(**gēng**), and as mentioned elsewhere, is a variant of「羹」. The whole sign says:

> 早餐 (*BREAKFAST*)
>
> - 飯 (*Rice dishes*)
> - 麵 (*Noodle dishes*)
> - 焿 (*Soup dishes*)

Answer (score 2):

> I couldn't find [it] in Pleco.

Here's a simple way to find it in [Pleco](https://store.pleco.com/products.php?ios=1). You need to have the:

> Fullscreen Handwriting Recognizer ($9.99)

add-on activated in Pleco.

Then all you have to do is *write* the character out to the best of your ability:

[image: yoyoyo]

and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Wow, that handwriting recognition is a *paid* feature? I thought I got it for free.

Comment: @droooze It's included in a lot of bundles & maybe it's free on Andorid, if I remember correctly(?).

Comment: I was trying to use the handwriting recognizer that comes with Android Pleco. I usually find it's pretty good at foreigners silly attempts with wrong number and order of strokes, but I can see now that I was drawing an extra stroke and maybe didn't interpret which strokes join up. In this case I couldn't get it to recognize my attempts. I'll try now that I know how it should be handwritten... No I still can't get it. Maybe this one is less forgiving about wrong stroke orders? No, even mimicking an animated stroker order site I can't get it.

Comment: @hippietrail if you're curious as to why the recognition doesn't show up, maybe you can post one of your attempts at handwriting it?

Comment: @hippietrail emulating the stroke order should definitely bring it up, 焿 is not even a "rare" character, so to speak. Maybe you can try what droooze said and show us how you're doing it then we can see what's going on.